# Bounded holomorphic functions on hypersurfaces of $\Bbb C^n$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-geometry

Is it true that every  bounded holomorphic functions on a smooth analytic hypersurface $X$ of $\Bbb C^n$ is constant?

- Remark that if $X$ is algebraic, the answer is yes.

Otherwise can you provide counterexamples?

Comment: That is not even true for $n$ equals $1$ and algebraic hypersurfaces.  The restriction of the holomorphic function $z$ to the hypersurface $\text{Zero}(z(z-1))$ is not constant.

Comment: Please forgive me - I suppose $X$ connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true: there are smooth hypersurfaces (even curves in $C^2$)
which are holomorphically equivalent to the unit disk in the plane.

MR1359950 
Globevnik, Josip, Stensønes, Berit,
Holomorphic embeddings of planar domains into $C^2$. 
Math. Ann. 303 (1995), no. 4, 579–597.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you find an similar answer if I suppose moreover that $X$ is simply connected?

Comment: The surface I mentioned in my answer is biholomorphically equivalent to the unit disk, therefore it is simply connected.

Comment: Ops! Sorry for the distraction. The situation I really would like to understand is the following: Let $\Lambda$ be  a lattice in $\Bbb C^n$ and $T=\Bbb C^n/\Lambda$ be the corresponding torus ($n\geq 3$). Suppose that $T$ is an abelian variety. Denote by $f: \Bbb C^n\to T$ the projection.  Let $X\subset T$ be a smooth ample divisor. Can we find bounded holomorphic functions on (a connected component of) $f^{-1}(X)$? if, I believe that, by lefschetz theorem, $f^{-1}(X)$ should be simply connected, and in the case

Comment: when $n=2$, $f^{-1}(X)$ is parabolic.

Comment: This is a completely new, different question. Ask it separately, and I will try to answer.

Comment: @carletto : By a theorem of V Ya Lin Math of USSR Sbornik 60 1988,197-216 titled Liouville covering of complex spaces and amenable groups, it follows by Lefschetz that X has abelian fundamental group ,hence by Lin's theorem no covering of X has nonconstant bounded holomorphiic functions.

Comment: @Mohan Ramachandran : Thanks a lot! this is exactly what I needed!